# Dock that supports 1 monitor @ 1440p@60hz, with Ethernet and a bunch of USB-A's

Tags: hub, docking-stations

I'm looking for a good cheap USB-C/thunderbolt dock that supports one monitor @ 1440p60, and has at least 2 USB-A ports. Also keen to have gigabit ethernet but that's less critical. I **don't** need passthrough power (as my laptop is too hungry for that), so it should be a 'passive' hub, i.e. powered by the computer.

More broadly: There are many, many little hubs like this on Amazon, almost all of which support power passthrough via a PD type C port that you plug a power brick into, and support "HDMI 4K@30hz, 1080p@60hz", can I be confident that these will:

- support 1440p60
- work in a passive mode, i.e. not ***require*** an external power source plugged into it